# Is there a proper map $\mathbb{A}^2\to \mathbb{A}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Is there a proper map of varieties $\mathbb{A}^2_k\to \mathbb{A}^1_k$?

My intuition says that this shouldn't be possible but I can't give a formal argument for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Any map of affine schemes is affine, and any map which is simultaneously affine and proper is finite. But $\Bbb A^2\to\Bbb A^1$ is not finite.